# iptables --tcp-flags

Tags: iptables

Question 1: are the following rules equal?

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
```

Question 2: are the following rules equal?

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
```

I'm new to iptables and I'm a bit confused because some tutorials suggest to use those four rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are for both the questions.

`ALL` is the same as `FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG`.

Check out the `man iptables-extensions` command on `--tcp-flags` which is used when the TCP protocol is used: `-p tcp`.

```
[!] --tcp-flags mask comp
          Match when the TCP flags are as specified.  The  first  argument
          mask  is  the flags which we should examine, written as a comma-
          separated list, and the second argument comp  is  a  comma-sepa‐
          rated  list  of flags which must be set.  Flags are: SYN ACK FIN
          RST URG PSH ALL NONE.  Hence the command
           iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN,RST SYN
          will only match packets with the SYN flag set, and the ACK,  FIN
          and RST flags unset.
```